# How to get elements from Linked list using get method

Tags: java, android, parsing, linked-list

I am developing a radio streaming application in android , I have a url in my linked list which is a parsed content from a .pls file link , What i needed is to parse the content from the url for that I need to get the elements from my linked list using get(position) method.Can anybody have any suggestions here I need help.

Here is a code snippet ,I want to use the url from the linked list to `player=MediaPlayer.create(this,Uri.parse("//Url from linked list"));`

I have the parsed url from .pls file link in my Linked List and all I need is to get the elements from linked list
Linked list object

```
LinkedList<String> urls;

private LinkedList<String> fGetPlayableUrl( String mPls) {
        GetStreamingUrl oGetStreamingUrl = new GetStreamingUrl(MainActivity.this);
        urls=new LinkedList<String>();
        urls = oGetStreamingUrl.getStreamingUrl(mPls);


        return urls;
    }

private void initializeMediaPlayer() throws IOException {
        player = new MediaPlayer();


        //int i ;
       /* for (i=0;i<='\0';i++)
        {

        }*/
       //URL=urls.get(2).toString();
        try {
     player=MediaPlayer.create(this,Uri.parse("//url here"));

            player.setDataSource(URL);
            //player.prepareAsync();
            //player.start();

        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        player.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(new OnBufferingUpdateListener() {

            public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
                playSeekBar.setSecondaryProgress(percent);
                Log.i("Buffering", "" + percent);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: linked list has list.get(index) method you can use it directly, is that your question?

Comment: post the code what you did.

Comment: please post lisnklist object as well

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try to put `player=MediaPlayer.create(this,Uri.parse("//url here"));` inside the loop of your link list just like this:

```
  LinkedList<String> urls;



     // Just make this method void. 
     //Anyways your LinkedList is still accessible globally 
     //and you are instantiating your linkedlist inside this method;
    private void fGetPlayableUrl( String mPls) {
            GetStreamingUrl oGetStreamingUrl = new GetStreamingUrl(MainActivity.this);
            urls=new LinkedList<String>();
            urls = oGetStreamingUrl.getStreamingUrl(mPls);
        }

    private void initializeMediaPlayer() throws IOException {
            player = new MediaPlayer();


            //int i ;
           /* for (i=0;i<='\0';i++)
            {

            }*/
           //URL=urls.get(2).toString();

    fGetPlayableUrl(url String here);

         for(String url:urls){
             try {

         player=MediaPlayer.create(this,Uri.parse(url));

                player.setDataSource(URL);
                //player.prepareAsync();
                //player.start();

            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            player.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(new OnBufferingUpdateListener() {

                public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
                    playSeekBar.setSecondaryProgress(percent);
                    Log.i("Buffering", "" + percent);
                }
            });
        }


        }
```